# How to render wordpress instead of default layout.hbs (handlebars) in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, handlebars.js

Builtin nodejs is using layout.hbs by default. But have to render wordpress instead of hbs

piece of code from app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('env', config.env || 'development');
```

How can i change my default layout to wordpress?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You want your ```/``` path to render a Wordpress blog and not a view ?

Comment: yes right. @MaquessimeChevallier.

Comment: But Wordpress works with PHP no ?

Comment: right so my question is how to render php instead of default layout.hbs in nodejs ? @MaquessimeChevallier

Answer (score 0):

A long way to render a wordpress page may be this:

1. Install the [WordPress REST API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) on your Wordpress site;
2. Recreate individual pieces of the wordpress template in hbs format;
3. On nodejs server, use the necessary wordpress APIs for composing the template and render it.

Comment: long way to go.. i recently heard of php-express.. trying to execute now. ever tried php-express ?

Comment: No, I never used this module. Looking at the guide, I suppose you know the php bin path for use this.